# AWS CLI Credentials configured, but not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've set up AWS CLI before without much difficulty, but I seem to be having a really weird problem this time. I set my keys up using `aws configure`, and when I use `aws configure list` they show up like this

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************REAL shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************KEYS shared-credentials-file    
    region                us-west-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

However when I try to run my code I `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`. In troubleshooting I've tried setting environment variables for the keys which also didn't work. The one thing that has helped is adding the keys directly to the calls in the code, but that is not ideal for the obvious reason of security plus it runs into credential issues every time s3 is used so that's just a lot to change.

Has anyone else ever run into this? And apologies if it's a duplicate everything I've found on here didn't have the keys showing up in `aws configure list` so I think it's different enough

Comment: Can you show your boto3 code that's failing? Does `aws sts get-caller-identity` work properly? Are you attempting to run the boto3 code using sudo?

Comment: In the implicit case, where you're expecting your app to retrieve credentials from `~/.aws/config`, ensure that you don't have any [AWS_xxx environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-list) set (you can use `env | grep AWS` to see them).

Comment: Oh interesting `aws sts get-caller-identity` gives me an SSL validation failure, the boto3 code it first fails on is just `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`, it's part of a python file and I am not using sudo

Comment: And I just did the grep to check the environment variables are gone

Comment: @lonely_wug can you show your ~/.aws/config (with credentials redacted)?

Comment: Yeah this is what the config looks like ```[default]
region = us-west-1
output = json``` I've tried putting the keys in there and taking them out and they haven't changed anything. My ~/.aws/credentials looks like ```[default]
aws_access_key_id = TOTALLY_REAL_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = SUPER_LEGIT_KEY```